# simplify multiple group clauses

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by

Ok, I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.[PAGE_ID] ,
       count(*) AS COUNT
FROM
  ( SELECT p.[PAGE_ID] ,
           o.country_id
   FROM [PAGES] p
   JOIN PAGE_ITEM_POSITION pip ON p.PAGE_ID = pip.PAGE_ID
   JOIN items i ON pip.item_id=i.item_id
   GROUP BY tp.PAGE_ID,
            i.country_id) AS p
GROUP BY p.page_id
```

So, pages have items, items have countries and items exist at a particular position on the page (This is not related to the issue though). Nothing really complicated here.

What I'm trying to find out, is how many different countries are represented on each pages, which is exactly what the query above does. However, I can't help but think that this is a little over complicated.

The inner query groups such that I get a direct listing of specific countries against pages, and then the outer part groups THAT result by the id again to give me the count.

Can this query be simplified?

Comment: It would be better if you can show us your DB schema..

Comment: will you plz create an sqlfiddle? Do u think the existing query is COMPLICATED?

Comment: No, I don't think it's COMPLICATED, but I do think it is more complicated THAN IT NEEDS TO BE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.[PAGE_ID], COUNT(DISTINCT i.country_id)
FROM [PAGES] p
INNER JOIN PAGE_ITEM_POSITION pip ON p.PAGE_ID = pip.PAGE_ID
INNER JOIN items i ON pip.item_id=i.item_id
GROUP BY p.PAGE_ID
```

Comment: That's great. exactly what I was looking for! I had a feeling I could do something with the count but could never quite put my finger on it.